How to Load Only Model Browser Data in Autodesk Forge Viewer Without Rendering the Entire Model?
I am currently using the Autodesk Forge Viewer (Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D) to display 3D models, some of which are quite large (around ~1GB). This size can create significant challenges for users with low bandwidth, as loading the entire model can be time-consuming and inefficient.
I’m looking for a solution that allows users to load only the data for the model browser, enabling them to partially load and view specific subtrees of the model, rather than having to download and render the entire model upfront.
Is there a way to access and interact with the model browser data without fully loading and rendering the entire 3D model?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
